# Create a new table from two existing tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join, create-table

I need to add a new column `cover_art`, to one of the tables that I referenced `news` when I created a new table `newsdetails` using JOIN but I can't remember how I did it.

Here's the table that includes the id `artistid` that is referenced in the the `artists` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
`post_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`artistid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`cover_art` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`blog_entry` text NOT NULL,
`updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`rating` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=76 ;


INSERT INTO `news` (`post_id`, `artistid`, `title`, `cover_art`, `blog_entry`,     `updated`, `rating`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Ultra', 'images/temp_cover.jpg', 'The very first track Barrel Of A Gun is blah blah.', '2012-11-19 16:23:19', '990,568'),
(2, 13, 'Mish Mash', 'images/temp_cover.jpg', 'A train pulls into a station and etc etc ad infinitum.', '2012-11-19 16:23:44', '831,880'),
```

And here's the `artists` table that has the id that I include in the `news`:

```
CREATE TABLE `artists` (
`id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`artists_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=170 ;


INSERT INTO `artists` (`id`, `artists_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Depeche Mode'),
(2, 'Amon Tobin'),
Etc.
```

I've looked into doing inner and left joins but can't for the life of me remember what I did to create this `newsdata` table that turns `artistid` into `artists_name`:

1   post_id smallint(5)     UNSIGNED    No  0
     2  title   varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
     3  blog_entry  text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
     4  updated timestamp           No  0000-00-00 00:00:00
     5  rating  varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
     6  artists_name    varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None

And thanks to eggyal for letting me know what FOREIGN KEYS are - i.e. NOT for doing this :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT news.post_id,
       news.title,
       news.blog_entry,
       news.updated,
       news.rating,
       artists.artists_name
FROM   news JOIN artists ON artists.id = news.artistid
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, that's way cleaner than what I was coming up with, although I'm mainly stuck on the code that turns it into a table that I can access from php in my website. Down the road I'll add queries within the head of the page Etc to get data from different tables that way, but for now I"m looking at creating one master table I can pull data from that way. I currently have a table called newsdata that I'm accessing.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I now have this, which works, but turning it into a table?                                                          SELECT news.post_id,
       news.title,
       news.cover_art,
       news.blog_entry,
       news.updated,
       news.rating,
       artists.artists_name
FROM   news JOIN artists ON artists.id = news.artistid

Comment: Bam, your answer left me with one simple addon - thanks eggyal     CREATE TABLE bingo SELECT news.post_id,
       news.title,
       news.cover_art,
       news.blog_entry,
       news.updated,
       news.rating,
       artists.artists_name
FROM   news JOIN artists ON artists.id = news.artistid

Comment: @PaulSeattle: It's unusual to create another table from the results of a query like this (you'd only really do it if you wanted to create a cached snapshot of the data).  Instead, you'd normally run queries of this sort in PHP to obtain the resultset as required.